# Azure automation Jobs that completed with errors - JobStreams data not forwarded to Azure Monitor

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

**Background**:

I have an Automation Account with one Runbook configured.

The runbook initiates a job which is a one PowerShell line that is syntactically wrong on purpose (`Write-Hos "Hello error`").

The typical result of this runbook running is a job with the following details:

[image]

I have one "**Diagnostic setting**" rule that is forwarding JobLogs, JobStreams, and Metrics to a Log Analytics Workspace.

[image]

I am using a system-assigned identity for this setup with no additional configuration to this identity other than enabling it when the automation account was created.

**The problem**

The ultimate goal is run this built-in query `Runbook completed successfully with errors` which will list all runbook jobs that are Completed (Job status = "Complete") but the job encountered errors. (To my understanding "Job Streams" refer to the detailed logs generated during the execution of a runbook job. Which is different than the "Job Status")

This is the query details as per Azure built-in `Runbook completed successfully with errors` query:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION" and Category == "JobStreams" and StreamType_s == "Error" 
| project TimeGenerated , RunbookName_s , StreamType_s , _ResourceId , ResultDescription , JobId_g
```

This however, doesn't return any data. After investigating the issue, I think the problem lies with the fact that the "`AzureDiagnostics`" table which stores this data, simply doesn't have it:

- I don't have any columns for job streams, such as `StreamType_s`.
- I don't have a value of "JobStreams" for the `Category` column.

I am not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use below `KQL` query that provides the details about the completed runbook job status with errors.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION" and Category == "JobStreams" and StreamType_s == "Error" 
| project TimeGenerated , RunbookName_s , StreamType_s , _ResourceId , JobId_g
```

*Path:* `Automation account >> Monitoring >> Logs >> Automation Jobs`

[image]

Use below query if you want to retrieve only the job logs with result type as failed.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION" and Category == "JobLogs" and ResultType == "Failed"
| project TimeGenerated , RunbookName_s , ResultType , JobId_
```

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics#query-the-logs) for the relevant information.

Comment: As I detailed in my original post, that query doesn't work because my AzureDiagnostics table does not have such data. It doesn't have a Category of value of "JobStreams". The table itself does not have a column called "StreamType_s". And that is my struggle, I don't have the data that is everyone pointing to. And I don't know what's missing from my Diagnostics settings (if anything) to get that data captured.

Comment: I updated the question based on some new understandings I have to propose the question and problem better (or I hope).

Comment: Have you added the diagnostic settings in automation account as well as the corresponding storage or log analytics workspace. @YousefImran

Comment: I've answered my own question. And yes, I have done what you mentioned. I checked it a few times and nothing was obvious. Eventually, I deleted the diagnostic setting and recreated it. Same exact options, just a different name, and that worked. Check my answer for details and thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact specifics, but **potentially** it could of have been one of the following:

1. Issues with the Diagnostics setting instance.
2. Timing issue.

**Details**:

I deleted the original *Diagnostics setting* rule that I have configured on the automation account and simply recreated it under a different name (just being superstitious) then I ran the runbook once (which created a job). I believe this was 5 - 10 minutes after I created the new Diagnostic setting.

The JobLogs data came in much quicker than JobStreams data (when I trying to query the workspace logs about 5 minutes after the job had completed).

While keep refreshing the query editor and running the same query again:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION"
```

The JobStreams came in (I'd say roughly between 15-30 minutes after the job had completed)

Although I ran around 4 jobs on the old instance of Diagnostic settings that I deleted, which some of them should of have been captured (if it was a timing issue), nonetheless, I won't rule that out.

The **solution** to me (and by observation but rather than fact) was to delete the old Diagnostic settings rule and create recreate it.